# If $s$ and $t$ are relatively prime, show that $f : x \rightarrow (x$ mod $s, x$ mod $t)$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $s$ and $t$ are relatively prime, show that $f : x \rightarrow (x$ mod $s, x$ mod $t)$ is an isomorphism from $U(st)$ to $U(s) \oplus U(t)$ where $U(n)$ is the set $1$ and all numbers less than $n$ that do not divide $n$ with multiplication modulo $n$ as the operation.

I understand that $f$ is onto by construction and the operation preserving is easily proven, but I'm having trouble showing this is $1-1$.

I start with $f(a) = f(b)$ and try to prove $a = b$.

This means that $(a$ mod $s, a$ mod $t) = (b$ mod $s, b$ mod $t)$.

This implies that $(a$ mod $s) = (b$ mod $s)$ and $(a$ mod $t) = (b$ mod $t)$.

But from here I can't see any way to prove that $a = b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\ s,t\mid a\!-\!b\,\Rightarrow\, st\mid a\!-\!b\ $ since $\,s,t\,$ are coprime so their lcm $=$ product.

Comment: So $(a-b)$ mod $st = 0 \Rightarrow a$ mod $st = b$ mod $st$, so because $gcd(s,t) = 1$ and $lcm(s,t) = st,$ then in $U(st)$, $a,b \lt st$ so $a=b$?

Comment: @OliverG $\ $ Yes, $\ st\mid a-b \,\Rightarrow\, a\equiv b\pmod{st},\ $ thus $\,f(a) = f(b) \,\Rightarrow\, a = b\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z/(st) = $ integers mod $\,st,\ $ so $\,f\,$ is $1$-$1$ (injective). $\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

You know that $s \mid (a-b) $ and you know that $t \mid (a-b)$. 
Since $s,t$ are co-prime, this implies that $st \mid (a-b)$, which is what you need.

Tangentially, I would not say that "onto" follows by construction.

Answer (score 0):

By chinese remainder theorem you have that $\mathbb{Z}_{st}\cong \mathbb{Z}_s \oplus \mathbb{Z}_t$ . It is very easy to see that the field of  units in the ring of the left side must be isomorphic the field of unit of the ring on side . so you get the result as soon as you realise that the set of unit in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n=U(n)$.